# Running git clone https://github.com/bergie/create.git failed with 128

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm installing Symfony-CMF(https://github.com/symfony-cmf/standard-edition)

When I updated composer, it returns this error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
Download or update create
fatal: la referencia no es un árbol: a148ce9633535930d7b4b70cc1088102f5c5eb90
Script Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CreateBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                                      
  Running git clone https://github.com/bergie/create.git failed with 128
```

This is my composer.json

```
{
"name" : "myProject",
"description" : "Project Debug",
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "" : "src/"
    }
},
"repositories" : [{
        "type" : "package",
        "package" : {
            "name" : "jquery/jquery",
            "version" : "1.10.2",
            "dist" : {
                "url" : "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js",
                "type" : "file"
            }
        }
    }
],
"minimum-stability" : "dev",
"provide" : {
    "lib-ICU" : "4.9"
},
"require" : {
    "sopinet/composergeneric" : "dev-master",
    "jms/payment-core-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "jms/payment-paypal-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "wisembly/excelant": "*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "dev-master",
    "lunetics/locale-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.2.*",
    "symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.1.*",
    "nelmio/alice": "~1.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "1.2-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Someone can help me? I've checked it on other project and it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it your linux machine ? If answer is "yes" then please add sudo before your command or give create/write permission that directory where you want to create your project.

Comment: @hizbul25, it hasn't worked... :( 777 permissions to all project but error persist, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rm -rf vendor/* and reinstall